# Discord.js | Buttons doesn't work after bot restarts

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

The buttons work after doing the command but after restarting the bot and pressing the button, it says `interaction failed` Here's my ticket.js

```
const { MessageButton } = require('discord-buttons');

module.exports = {
    name: 'ticket-setup',
    aliases: ['close'],
    category: 'Miscellaneous',
    description: 'Makes a ticket embed',
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord){

        if(!message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) return message.reply("Normies can't do this command")

        if (cmd == 'close') {
            if (!message.channel.name.includes('ticket-')) return message.channel.send('You cannot use that here!');
            message.channel.delete();
           }
       
        let title;
        let desc;
        let ticketMsg;

        const filter = msg => msg.author.id == message.author.id;
        let options = {
            max: 1
        };
    
        message.channel.send("What will the ticket title be?\nSay cancel to cancel")
        let col = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, options)
        if(col.first().content == 'cancel') return message.channel.send("Cancelled");
        title = col.first().content
    
        message.channel.send('What will the description be?\nSay cancel to cancel')
        let col2 = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, options)
        if(col2.first().content == 'cancel') return message.channel.send("Cancelled");
        desc = col2.first().content
        
        message.channel.send('What is the message that the user will see when they make a ticket?\nSay cancel to cancel')
        let col3 = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, options)
        if(col3.first().content == 'cancel') return message.channel.send("Cancelled");
        ticketMsg = col3.first().content

        const setupEmbed =  new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(title)
        .setDescription(desc)
        .setFooter(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .setColor('00f8ff')

        const hiEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .addField(ticketMsg, "\n\nDo a.close or press the button to close the ticket")
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setTimestamp()
        
        const createTicketButton = new MessageButton()
        .setID("ticketCreate")
        .setStyle("blurple")
        .setLabel("");

        const closeTicketButton = new MessageButton()
        .setID("ticketClose")
        .setLabel("Close ticket")
        .setStyle("red");



        if(cmd == 'ticket-setup'){ 
        message.channel.send({embed: setupEmbed, button: createTicketButton })      
        }

           client.on('clickButton', async (button) => {
            await button.clicker.fetch();
            await button.reply.defer();
               const user = button.clicker.user
            if (button.id === 'ticketCreate') {
              button.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${user.id}`,  {
                permissionOverwrites: [
                 {
                  id: user.id,
                  allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                 },
                 {
                  id: button.message.guild.roles.everyone,
                  deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                 },
                ],
                type: 'text',
               }).then(async (channel) =>{
                   channel.send({embed: hiEmbed, button: closeTicketButton })
               })
            } else if(button.id == 'ticketClose'){
                button.message.channel.delete()
            }
          });
    }
}
```

I use the package `discord-buttons` [Docs link](https://discord-buttons.js.org)

I tried putting the clickButton event in my event handler but it didn't work as I get a lot of errors. How do I still make the buttons work even after restart?

Comment: Using your event handler/listener is the only way for buttons to work after a restart since both the button collector and awaitButtons stop listening when it restarts.  You're better off trying to solve your errors than avoiding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Problem**

The reason why your buttons aren't working after your bot restarts is because your `client.on("clickButton")` event handler is *inside* your "ticket-setup" command's code. That means your event is only setup once the ticket-setup command is used after the bot restarts, or in other words once `execute()` is called on this file after the bot has started up.

Think about this: your `client.on("clickButton")` code is not reached until your `ticket-setup` command's `execute()` function is called. This will cause multiple problems for you. First of all, as mentioned above, the `clickButton` event is not even being handled until you've used `ticket-setup` at least once after the bot has started up. Secondly, this will create *an additional event handler every time the command is used*. In other words, if you were to use the `ticket-setup` command twice or more, the code within your `clickButton` handler would execute *more than once* every time your buttons are clicked (in your specific scenario, it would create more than one ticket per button click).

**The Solution**

The problem you are facing has a pretty simple solve. You simply need to move the entirety of your `clickButton` event handler out of the `execute()` method. Perhaps move it into your main `server.js` or `bot.js` file, alongside your `client.on("ready")` and `client.on("message")` event handlers. This will ensure that the `clickButton` event handler is setup only once, and immediately when the bot starts up.

Note, however, that you do need to make some slight additions to your `clickButton` event handler to ensure this works properly. You need to move the code for your `hiEmbed` and `closeTicketButton` into your `client.on("clickButton")` handler.

Here's how that might look, in `server.js`, based on the code in your question:

```
client.on('clickButton', async (button) => {        
    await button.clicker.fetch();
    await button.reply.defer();
    const user = button.clicker.user;

    const hiEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .addField(ticketMsg, "\n\nDo a.close or press the button to close the ticket")
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setTimestamp();

    const closeTicketButton = new MessageButton()
    .setID("ticketClose")
    .setLabel("Close ticket")
    .setStyle("red");

    if (button.id === 'ticketCreate') {
        button.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${user.id}`,  {
            permissionOverwrites: [
            {
                id: user.id,
                allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            },
            {
                id: button.message.guild.roles.everyone,
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            },
            ],
            type: 'text',
        }).then(async (channel) =>{
            channel.send({embed: hiEmbed, button: closeTicketButton })
        })
    } else if(button.id == 'ticketClose'){
        button.message.channel.delete()
    }
});
```

You may have noticed another problem with this: the `ticketMsg` variable will not be defined. You will need to make changes to solve that issue as well. I would recommend saving the value of `ticketMsg` to a JSON file or database, and accessing that information within your `client.on("clickButton")`. If this code represents a proper ticketing system, you will need to do this regardless of whether you use this solution or not, as otherwise your users will need to use `ticket-setup` to setup the ticketing system again *every time your bot restarts*.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I moved the clickButton event to my event handler and made the `ticketMsg`  saved into a database it works fine now, also thanks for explaining and making it better for me to understand!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, but instead of interaction failed, I got incomplete button info.

```js
client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', interaction => {
//complete interaction
})
```

Buttons are interactions which trigger this, and you can check whether this is a slash command or button with `interaction.data.custom_id` (This may be wrong, I couldn’t test it). It will be undefined if it isn’t a button, but will hold the custom id of the button if it is a button.

Comment: should I put that in my event handler or in the command file? and what do I have to add in it? I tried Squiddleton's suggestion and it did work even after restart, it's just that it returns `ticketMsg` as either undefined or just something else

Comment: Instead of client.on('clickButton' replace it with that

Comment: Two things to note. A) Both button and select menu interactions use `custom_id`, so this answer would also trigger for select menus (which could cause errors if the OP wants to use select menus as well). The best way to differentiate between slash commands, buttons, and select menus is to use `interaction.data.component_type`, which is specifically designed to differentiate between these. The component type of buttons is `2`, so just check if it equals 2. B) If you look at the code of `discord-buttons`, this event handler is exactly what it's using to power `clickButton` anyways.